# Differing state in select input and dynamic url in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms, state

I have a select input pulling JSON data of Japanese prefectures using React.  Users select prefectures by name.

The select input value is set as `state.prefecture`, which calls "Tokyo", for example. I'm mapping this data to the select options from a local JSON file.

In the dynamic URL JSON fetch call `${state.prefecture}`, I need the prefectural code instead of the name, "13" in the case of Tokyo.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you map your data to the select options from a local JSON file, at that point you can store prefectural code for that particular value into some other variable using {this.state.prefecture.id} as per your API data.

Then use that data for the fetch call lets say by ${this.state.prefecture.id}.

Answer (score 0):

I set the option value equal to the prefectural code, then set the select input value to `value={(state.prefecture, state.code)}`